# Nestjs как с помощью exeption filter подавить ошибку в контроллер kafka?

Tags: nestjs

Exeption filter для микросервисов. Какой observable надо вернуть чтобы подавить ошибку?

Comment: https://nestjs.ru/microservices/exception-filters#filters